# Is jquery's attr() asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

Say I have a loop that on each iteration it appends a div with an img tag, then loads its src attribute using something like this:

```
$("img").last().attr('src', imageSource);
```

If I'm doing this for a few iterations for a few different images, am I getting an asynchronous loading of those images?

If not, how do I load images asynchronously by looping? I'll be happy to get some ajax tips.

Comment: attribute is set immediately, but images load asynchronously

Comment: You can use [load() function](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) to perform code AFTER your images were loaded.

Comment: Could you give an example on the piece of code above? @ZathrusWriter

Comment: @user1639431 I think I misread the question - thought you're trying to retrieve your image source for some reason, not assign it to the image... sorry, my bad :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`attr` is not asynchronous. It is a very simple operation that takes place effectively instantly.

However, the loading of the images from the server takes rather longer. That process *is* asynchronous: as soon as you set the attribute, you can forget about it and the browser will load the image for you in the background.

Loading images asynchronously isn't an option: it is in fact the only way that images are loaded.

Comment: And how do I load images asynchronously with ajax?

Comment: You can't load images with AJAX. All you do is set the `src` attribute of an element and the browser loads the image.

Comment: What do you need `.load()` for?