# jQuery submit(); not picking up value

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button, submit

I'm using image replacements for radio buttons by hiding the buttons and selecting them depending on what image is clicked.

When an image is clicked I want them to select a radio button, and then submit.

This is my original code:

```
$('#settings img').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(":radio").attr('checked', true);
});
```

This works if I click on an image and then submit.

I extended it to submit the form on click:

```
$('#settings img').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(":radio").attr('checked', true);
  $("#settings").submit();
});
```

In this case, the form submits but it does not change the value. If I submit it by clicking the button, it works fine.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: How does your HTML look?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eLGBt/ thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was the `true` value given to the `checked` attribute.

The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLGBt/) provided **works** in Chrome. But it **doesn't** in Firefox. To make it work also in Firefox, use the `checked` value for the `checked` attribute.

```
$('#settings img').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(":radio").attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

An alternative would be to **directly** manipulate (as well) the `checked` property of the DOM element:

```
$(this).parent().find(":radio").get(0).checked = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

Javascript is asynchronous.
It looks like the form is submitting before jQuery can check the checkbox. Try putting the submit in a callback:

```
$('#settings img').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(":radio").attr('checked', true).one('change', function(){
     $("#settings").submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah of course, you're right. I believe adding .attr('checked', true).one('change', function(){ .. callback code .. }); will work but I can't test at the moment

Comment: though it is true that javascript has some asynchronous functionality and many things in jquery use that. I do not believe `attr()` to be one of those things. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289284/is-jquerys-attr-asynchronous) this is not his problem. (redid comment because because autocorrect corrected wrong)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not the best answer but if you give your images an class you can replace : #settings img with .image then it works

Comment: Strange, i even removed all other JS code to see if it was conflicting with something but it still didn't work.

Comment: The above problem is cause by the value of the `checked` attribute that should be `checked` instead of `true`

Answer (score -2):

I've forked your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/fC38V/ and made some additions:

```
$('#settings').submit(function(){
    alert($(this).serialize());
});

$('#settings img').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(":radio").attr('checked', true);
    $("#settings").submit(); // submits form on click
});​
```

By adding a submit handler before your click handler and testing the forked fiddle, I can only verify that it works as intended (as far as I can tell by the description) in my browser (Safari 6.0.1 on Mac OS X 10.8).

Please make sure that:

1. there are no nester forms. browsers can get really picky about this.
2. there are is only one element with the id "#settings"

The only other possible problem I can come up with is your browser... what are you using?

Comment: This is really a comment... not an answer.

Comment: somewhat true, but this way i can track the question to answer it later.

Comment: That's what the [favorite functionality](http://i.imgur.com/B6stQ.png) is for. You'll get notifications of any change to this post... Please only post an answer if you are actually attempting to **answer the question**. All you are doing here is asking another question.

Comment: @Kris We'd rather you use this resource as the simple [rules](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) see fit, but I'm not removing this answer. It is an attempt to help the OP, awaiting a bit of clarification. If abandoned, it would only be a potentially wrong answer. We have lots of those.

Comment: Why am I defending actually trying to help someone to people here?! even the original one liner contained two potentially very helpful pointers. I did not violate any rules that I am aware of other then get a little pissed off because people judge without understanding or frankly reading. I could have posted the one liner in a comment but since it did actually attempt to answer the question...

Comment: your example worked on jsfiddle but it stopped it from working on my page, there are no nester forms and only 1 element is has an id of #settings. strange.

Comment: I'll complete source to the page and its resources then. is the page publicly available by some url? and what browser are you using?

Comment: http://newsite.interviewhub.co.uk/account/plans. I should reiterate that it does capture the value on the alert, but it does not post it to the form.

Comment: Works fine for me, but my safari does tell me there are 2 issues wit some resources on the page: in "rules.js" => undefined is not a function on line 28. in "js" => too many redirects